# Error installing libsigsegv on ubuntu

Tags: unix, clisp

While installing libsigsegv for clisp, I have run into an error. "make install" does not finish correctly. The problem as I can see it is a permission issue. I am very new to Unix and cant figure out how to solve this issue. Can you help me please to solve this issue? Any suggestions highly appreciated.

```
me@me-VPCSB11FX:~/school/summer/libsigsegv/libsigsegv$ make install
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/me/school/summer/libsigsegv/libsigsegv/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/me/school/summer/libsigsegv/libsigsegv/src'
test -z "/usr/local/lib" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib"
/bin/bash ../libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c  'libsigsegv.la'   '/usr/local/lib/libsigsegv.la'
/usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsigsegv.lai /usr/local/lib/libsigsegv.la
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libsigsegv.la': Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/me/school/summer/libsigsegv/libsigsegv/src'
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/me/school/summer/libsigsegv/libsigsegv/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: which ubuntu version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation step is trying to write to a shared directory `/usr/local/lib`, which is read-only for end users and writable only for administrators and such.

You would need to give yourself additional privilleges by using `su` or `sudo` -- see e.g. [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/How-To-Temporarily-Change-Accounts-And-Privileges.htm).

Also please note that installing custom stuff this way of `make install` is not very nice nowadays. You should be using some *package management system* like RPM or Aptitude or whatever, depending on your Unix distribution. It handles uninstallation, dependencies, conflicts, updates and everything else automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The detailed installation instructions are found in the INSTALL or INSTALL.generic file, for every GNU package. For GNU libiconv it is this file: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=libsigsegv.git;a=blob;f=INSTALL

The default installation location, `/usr/local`, is not writable by an ordinary user. You have three options:

- Use `sudo make install` instead of `make install`.
- Make the `/usr/local` directory and its subdirectory owned by yourself, instead of owned by root: `chown -R $(id -u -n) /usr/local`
- Specify a different installation directory (see section "Installation Names" of said INSTALL file): For example: `./configure --prefix=${HOME}/gnu/arch/$(uname -p)`